# What is the mistake in this SQL statement? - SQL

Tags: sql

SQL query:

```
insert into Transaction_Details (Trans_Date, Trans_Type)
values (GetDate(), 'WITHDRWAL')
from Transaction_Details t 
inner join Acc_Details a on t.UserID = a.UderId
where a.Card_No = '1234567890123456';
```

Transaction table columns:

```
Trans_ID int PRIMARY KEY IDENTITY(1,1),
Trans_Date datetime,
Trans_Type varchar(20),
UserID int foreign key references User_Details(UserID)
Card_Id varchar(16) foreign key references User_Card_Details,
Acc_No int foreign key references Acc_Details(Acc_No)
```

Acc_Details columns:

```
Acc_Id int,
Acc_No int PRIMARY KEY,
Card_No varchar(16)  foreign key references User_Card_Details(Card_No),
UserId int foreign key references User_Details(UserID),
Balance int,
BankName varchar(15)
```

I get this error:

> Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'from'

Comment: Maybe a typo: `t.UserID = a.UserId` insteat of `t.UserID = a.UderId`?

Comment: Do you want to insert one row with the `VALUES` clause or do you want to insert rows based on a query result? You have a mix. Either you `select ... from` or you insert `values(...)`. You cannot have both at the same time.

Answer (score 0):

To insert based on a select it's this:

```
insert into Transaction_Details (Trans_Date, Trans_Type)
select  GetDate(), 
        'WITHDRWAL'
from Transaction_Details t 
inner join Acc_Details a on t.UserID = a.UderId
where a.Card_No = '1234567890123456';
```

Comment: Do you really think he want this? To insert the date and the word WITHDRWAL as often as there are already rows in the table for users with that card number? This doesn't seem likely.

Comment: I must admit It seems odd...  But the question is only about the error in the SQL, so maybe it's what he wants.